# Как перенести div на следующий столбец?

Tags: css, css-grid

Хочу сделать калькулятор. Есть 4 `div` с кнопками и `label`, которые в столбцы собственно расположить и нужно.

Вот разметка:

```
 <div class="column">

                <label>Математика</label>

                <input type="button" name="plus" id ="plus" value="+">
                <input type="button" name="minus" id ="minus" value="-">
                <input type="button" name="multiply" id ="multiply" value="*">
                <input type="button" name="divide" id ="divide" value="/">
                <input type="button" name="pow" id ="pow" value="x^y">

                </div>


            <div class="column">

                <label>Алгебра</label>

                <input type="button" name="abs" id ="abs" value="abs">
                <input type="button" name="sort" id ="sort" value="sort">
                <input type="button" name="exp" id ="exp" value="exp">
                <input type="button" name="ln" id ="ln" value="ln">

                </div>


            <div class="column">

                <label>Тригонометрия</label>

                <input type="button" name="sin" id ="sin" value="sin">
                <input type="button" name="cos" id ="cos" value="cos">
                <input type="button" name="tg" id ="tg" value="tg">
                <input type="button" name="ctg" id ="ctg" value="ctg">

                </div>
```

css

```
.column {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
grid-auto-flow: column;

grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Почему все становится в один столбец. хотя столбцов я указал 4? Можно ли как то перенести `div` в 4 столбца не используя отдельный класс для каждого (вместе со свойством `grid-column-start`)? С отдельными классами css будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
.column1 {
 display : grid;
 grid-column-start: 1;
 }

 .column2 {
 display : grid;
 grid-column-start: 2;
 }
```

Но так делать совсем не хочется.

Comment: А нафига там `grid-auto-flow: column;`?

Comment: @Qwertiy чтоб кнопки "+" "-" и т.д шли не слева направо, а сверху вниз.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я имею ввиду кнопки одного столбца и его label. Другие столбцы должны быть не под предыдущим, а рядом с ним.